# Android App Installation Failed With Error: [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, dalvik

To preface my question, I have looked at all similar questions I can find on StackOverflow and also around the web with no success.  I have been developing using a real device for some months with no issue.  Yesterday I updated Android Studio, which I had previously been working with, to version 0.5.4.  This update required that I upgrade to Gradle version 0.9 as apparently the build system has some major changes.  Since upgrading my IDE, when I try to run my project on my device, I get the following output in the run console:

**Run Console Output**

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-sch_i605-42f7bff119a3bf69
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\student\Android studioProjects\DrunkModeAndroid\DrunkMode\build\apk\DrunkMode-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode
Installing com.launchfuture.drunk_mode
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode    // this line is red
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]                     // this line is also red
```

**Logcat Output**

```
04-06 14:44:00.066    8040-8040/? D/Finsky﹕ [1] WorkerTask.onPreExecute: Verification Requested for id = 21, data=file:///data/local/tmp/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode flags=114 fromVerificationActivity=false 
04-06 14:44:01.586  12740-12740/? W/dalvikvm﹕ DexOptZ: zip archive '/data/app/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode-1.apk' does not include classes.dex 
04-06 14:44:01.591    2001-2001/? W/installd﹕ DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode-1.apk' --- status=0xff00, process failed 
04-06 14:44:01.591    2001-2001/? E/installd﹕ dexopt failed on '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.launchfuture.drunk_mode-1.apk@classes.dex' res = 65280 
04-06 14:44:01.591    2410-2621/? W/PackageManager﹕ Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.launchfuture.drunk_mode-1.apk
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/GoogleAnalyticsServicesAndroid_3.01/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

My android device is rooted and therefore I am able to look through the file system at the specified locations.  Of note, the reference to `data@app@com.launchfuture.drunk_mode-1.apk@classes.dex` is not present in the `/data/dalvik-cache/` directory. Do any of you have experience handling this issue?

Comment: How much free space on `/data/dalvik-cache` ?

Comment: Try changing `0.9.+` to `0.9.0`. There were some problems with 0.9.1 and 0.9.2 of the plugin. I don't recall them having these symptoms, but it's worth a shot, since it's a one-character change. :-)

Comment: @EugenRieck I'm not familiar with how to determine the free space specific to that directory, but the internal storage on my device still has 3.6GB of free space.

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: There is no DEX file in `/data/dalvik-cache` because dexopt failed while trying to create it.  `does not include classes.dex` means your APK file doesn't have a "classes.dex" entry in it -- check it yourself with a Zip utility.

Comment: @fadden What you've said makes sense, I was under the impression that the `classes.dex` file is automatically generated when using Gradle as the build system.  How would I go about ensuring that the `classes.dex` file is included in future compilations of the APK file?

Comment: @Philip: I don't know.  I don't have the full answer, but I wanted to point out that wiping your dalvik-cache isn't going to help -- this is a build issue, not an install issue.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please empty the contents of /data/dalvik-cache and reboot (or wipe dalvik cache from recovery) so it gets rebuilt ?

Comment: When you say to empty the contents of /data/dalvik-cache, are you saying I should delete all the content in that directory for every app?

Comment: Well, instead of doing that, boot into recovery and wipe dalvik cache from recovery. This process would be less cumbersome.

Comment: @Philip : Did you try fadden's suggestion ? Did you check your APK with a zip utility for classes.dex ?

Comment: I get the same error but I can install our store version just not a debug version on my Droid3. I have classes.dex in my debug apk, at a loss for what is wrong with out debug apk.

Answer (score 0):

On a rooted mobile, install lucky patcher then go to option build and install through lucky patcher, go to desired apk in SD card which you want to install, tap it and select install as system app...after process reboot...it can work at the cost of mobile system app space.